# Creating dynamic dependent input filter for ggplot2 in shinyR Dashboard and render plot accordingly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create a ggplot that is rendered as per the 3 user input's which should be dependent of each other.

My data Set looks like this :

```
Week                  Region   Movement_Type    Warehouse  f_TAT     Quantity 
April 05 - April 11   North    Local            ABC        In TAT    10
April 05 - April 11   North    Local            ABC        Out TAT   5
April 05 - April 11   East     Local            ABC        In TAT    13
April 05 - April 11   East     Local            ABC        Out TAT   6
March 01 - March 07   West     Inter-State      XYZ        In TAT    15
March 01 - March 07   West     Inter-State      XYZ        Out TAT   10
```

What i have been able to achieve as of now:
I have been able to create the ggplot with 3 filter which as of now are not dependent of each other. When no particular filter is selected it shows the option of All as default. But it is plotting wrong plot

[image]

When I select the warehouse filter and region filter the data seems to change but is still displaying wrong plot .

[image]

My code that helped me achieve this :

```
    library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(gtools)

ui <- shinyUI(
  
  navbarPage(
    title = 'Dashboard',
    
    tabPanel('Performance',
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('Tab1',
                        fluidRow(
                          column(3,selectInput('warehouse', 'Select Warehouse', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Warehouse))))), 
                          column(3,selectInput('region', 'Select Region', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Region))))),
                          column(3,selectInput('mov_type', 'Select Movement Type', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Movement_Type))))),
                          column(12,plotlyOutput("myplot_fwd_f"))
                        )
               )
             )),
    
    
    tabPanel('Orders',
             fluidRow(
             )
    )
  )
  
  
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    plot1 <- read.csv("plot1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    temp <- plot1
    if (input$warehouse != "All"){
      temp <- temp[temp$Warehouse == input$warehouse,]
    }
    if (input$region != "All"){
      temp <- temp[temp$Region == input$region,]
    }
    if (input$mov_type != "All"){
      temp <- temp[temp$Movement_Type == input$mov_type,]
    }
    return(temp)
  })

  output$myplot_fwd_f <- renderPlotly({

    data <- data1()
    p<- ggplot(data, aes(fill=f_TAT, y=Quantity , x=reorder(Week, + Week))) + 
      geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",colour="black") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#44E62F", "#EC7038")) +
      labs(x = "Week") +
      labs(y = "Percentage") +
      labs(title = "") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
      geom_text(data = . %>%
                  group_by(Warehouse,Region,Movement_Type,Week) %>%
                  mutate(p = Quantity  / sum(Quantity )) %>%
                  ungroup(),
                aes(y = p, label = scales::percent(p)),
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                show.legend = FALSE) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 10))
    p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
    p
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I want to know if there is a way to make the 3 filters dependent of each other ? As as of now they display all the unique values they can find in the particular column of the data base.

When by default all three filters have "All" option selected in them they seems to be plotting all the possible combinations on the plot, how can this be corrected.

And lastly can I change the 3rd "Movement Type" filter into a Multi Check-Box option filter?

Thank you.

Edit : Thank you so much @YBS i was able to achieve the dependent filter's all thanks to you .. @YBS as per stated in your comment below it is showing multiple % for In TAT/ Out Tat Reason being there are multiple values for In/Out TAT for a particular week. Can we try to show the overall percentage of a week instead of multiple In TAT/ Out TAT % ? That would solve my last remaining problem. Thank you again for your help.

Edit 2 : Hi YBS thank you for the Update. The final Output looks like this now.
[image]

It seems it is still dividing it into different level's, is there a way to show only one % of In/Out TAT for a week. One thing I also noticed that The 3rd filter when only one filter is selected instead of all it show's this error "Error : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable", Even when there is a data set for the filter applied. Do i need to expand the data set for your better understanding ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `updateSelectInput()` to update the values of the subsequent `selectInput`s.  Then you need to `group_by` only `Week`. To aggregate per week some data processing is required.  Perhaps this meets your need.

```
df <- read.table(text=
"Week,                Region,   Movement_Type,    Warehouse,  f_TAT,     Quantity
April 05 - April 11,   North,    Local,            ABC,        In TAT,    10
April 05 - April 11,   North,    Local,            ABC,        Out TAT,   5
April 05 - April 11,   East,    Local,            ABC,        In TAT,    13
April 05 - April 11,   East,    Local,            ABC,        Out TAT,   6
March 01 - March 07,   West,     Inter-State,      XYZ,        In TAT,    15
March 01 - March 07,   West,     Inter-State,      XYZ,        Out TAT,   10", header=TRUE, sep=",")

library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(gtools)

plot1 <- df

ui <- shinyUI(

  navbarPage(
    title = 'Dashboard',

    tabPanel('Performance',
             tabsetPanel(
               tabPanel('Tab1',
                        fluidRow(
                          column(3,selectInput('warehouse', 'Select Warehouse', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Warehouse))))),
                          column(3,selectInput('region', 'Select Region', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Region))))),
                          column(3,checkboxGroupInput("mov_type","Select Movement Type", inline = TRUE, choices = c("All",unique(plot1$Movement_Type)))),
                          #column(3,selectInput('mov_type', 'Select Movement Type', c("All",as.character(unique(plot1$Movement_Type))))),
                          column(12,plotlyOutput("myplot_fwd_f"))
                        )
               )
             )),


    tabPanel('Orders',
             fluidRow( DTOutput("t1")
             )
    )
  )

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data1 <- reactive({
    plot1 <- df # read.csv("plot1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    temp <- plot1
    if (input$warehouse != "All"){
      temp <- temp[temp$Warehouse == input$warehouse,]
    }
    return(temp)
  })

  observeEvent(input$warehouse, {
    df1 <- data1()
    updateSelectInput(session,"region",choices=c("All",as.character(unique(df1$Region))))
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$region)
    plot1 <- data1()
    temp <- plot1
    if (input$region != "All"){
      temp <- temp[temp$Region == input$region,]
    }
    tmp <- temp %>%
      group_by(Week) %>%
      mutate(p = Quantity  / sum(Quantity )) %>%
      ungroup()
    return(tmp)
  })

  observeEvent(input$region, {
    df2 <- req(data2())
    #updateSelectInput(session,"mov_type",choices=c("All",unique(df2$Movement_Type)) )
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"mov_type",choices=c("All",as.character(unique(df2$Movement_Type))), inline=TRUE, selected="All")
  })
  
  data3 <- reactive({
    req(input$mov_type)
    if ("All" %in% input$mov_type){ 
      data <- data2()
    }else{
      data <- data2()[data2()$Movement_Type %in% input$mov_type,]
    }
    tmp <- data %>%
      group_by(Week,f_TAT) %>%
      mutate(Quantity = sum(Quantity)) %>% distinct(Week,f_TAT,Quantity) %>% 
      group_by(Week) %>% 
      mutate(p = Quantity  / sum(Quantity )) %>%
      ungroup()
    return(tmp)
  })

  output$t1 <- renderDT(data3())

  output$myplot_fwd_f <- renderPlotly({
    
    data <- req(data3())

    p<- ggplot(data, aes(fill=f_TAT, y=p , x=Week)) +
      geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity",colour="black") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#44E62F", "#EC7038")) +
      labs(x = "Week") +
      labs(y = "Percentage") +
      labs(title = "") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
      geom_text(aes(y = p, label = scales::percent(p)),
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                show.legend = FALSE) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 10))
    p <- ggplotly(p) #, tooltip="text")
    p

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, I tried using the code suggested by you, faced a few problems like the second filter (Region) gets converted to integer format & the third filter(Movement Type) movement type looses its all filter option and does not update to any change , can we change the third filter into a multicheck box ? And The plot is still showing different level of % in a particular week, which it should show only X% of In Tat and Y% of Out TAT ,, not multiple in %'s for a particular week

Comment: Hi , YBS ,, thank you so much for your response It helped me achieve what i was hoping for ..I have edited my question with what the final output looks right now .. As you pointed out there are multiple % for a particular week that is why it's showing multiple %'s against week , As per the screenshot that i have edited in my original question, The multiple %'s are creating problem in the plot view can we not aggregate it to just overall % of In tat & Out TAT of the week.. Again i would like to thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you YBS for the prompt response, I have updated my original Question with the observation's. and screenshot of the final input. Kindly please have a look. Also Should i expand the data for your better understanding of the data set? Again Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That is a different issue than the original post.  Updating the same question too many times leads to confusion on the original intent.  Please post it as a separate question with more data records.  With only 6 rows, it is not possible to see your issues.

Comment: Hi Sir, unfortunately it didn't .. as per your sugestion i have created a new post with the current problem and an updated 86 Row's of data set . I think that would be able to help you .  Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046263/plotting-the-correct-percentage-labels-on-ggplot-through-dynamic-dependent-input